# Salesforce Calendar- create a button inside

Tags: custom-button, calendar, page-layout

I would like to know if is it possible create a custom button in salesforce calendar layout, I've been searching on google and I can´t find anything

The layout I'm talking about is this one:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now this is Not supported.

Here are the [Customization Options for Events and Calendars](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizeactivities_eventcaloptions.htm&type=0)

Or if you really need this then you can use [JavaScript Full Calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot edit standard calendar page but

You can try to create Salesforce Calendar Lightning Page with your own custom buttons

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_calendarview.htm?_ga=2.159489855.325540345.1658212256-612654447.1640704965